# How to change URL name using .htaccess without redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a script written in Laravel, which returns information about git repositories in JSON. I've set it on some server, however the URL looks like this:

`/GLara/public/repositories/{account_name}/{repository_name}`

and I would love to get it like this:

`/repositories/{account_name}/{repository_name}`

I've tried using `.htaccess`, but I don't know how to use it not to redirect a client to a directory that not exists (have 404 right now, because there is no such directory like /repositories in main catalog).

Could you please advise me how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/repositories/.*
RewriteRule ^/repositories(.*)$ /GLara/public/$1 [PT,L]
```